# Effect of dexamethasone iontophoreses on tendons

Tags: tendons, dexamethasone, iontophoresis

Are [dexamethasone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexamethasone) [iontophoreses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iontophoresis) used to treating a tendinopathy known to have any deleterious effect on tendons?

Answer (score 1):

The penetration is limited, therefore it's less risky than a steroid injection which carries a higher risk of tendon rupture<sup>[(1)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15069146)</sup>.

[Study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10372854) conclusion from 1999 ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.17.3136&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) by [SMJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Medical_Journal) was:

> Iontophoresis using sterile water or corticosteroid resulted in minimal or no biochemical and histologic changes in the tendon compared with injection of either substance. The method of corticosteroid delivery may be as important as the actual drug effects on the biomechanical and histologic properties of tendons.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.